# work around for python scripts which access sqlite database on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, sqlite

I have a very small, simple sqlite database, and several python scripts to access the database.  I want to run these scripts using Heroku, but it seems that Heroku doesn't support `sqlite3`.

I have tried adding the line

```
sqlite3==3.0
```

to my `requirements.txt` file before running

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but it says it can't find `sqlite3`.

What is the easiest, most lightweight way to be able to query my sqlite database on Heroku?

1. Do I need to convert the sqlite database?  If so, how do I do that?
2. If I'm not allowed to `import sqlite` in python on Heroku, what is the alternative package I need to use and how do I change my python code which calls execute statements like

   SELECT * FROM table

I find that the Heroku [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database) assumes that the user has a bit more expertise.  Also, it seems from other stackoverflow, blog posts that folks where somehow able to use `sqlite3` with Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external modulename would be [`pysqlite`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite).

However, Heroku runs Python 2.7 and if `import sqlite3` is not supported, Heroku will not have the pre-requisite sqlite C libraries installed. I thus suspect that loading the `pysqlite` module will not work either.

Note that there is really no point in using sqlite on the Heroku platform, as the filesystem is ephemeral; every time your app starts you have a clean slate and any writes performed by your app *disappear* once done. Since sqlite can only write to the local filesystem, this means the database will be gone the next time you start your app. See [Using Sqlite3 on Heroku Cedar stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784471/using-sqlite3-on-heroku-cedar-stack).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm still a bit confused about what the solution to using a database is. The answer to the link you provided says that Heroku provides a PostgreSQL "installation". Does that mean the if I migrate my database to PostgreSQL then they can also store it on Heroku permanently?  Is converting from sqlite to PostgreSQL fairly painless?

Comment: @erin: It should be fairly painless; PostgreSQL's dialect of SQL is richer, so you'll have more features than sqlite can offer. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database for info on PostgreSQL. Yes, the data stored in the PostgreSQL database would be permanent.